# How to troubleshoot a Python Azure Function "An unhandled exception has occurred"?

Tags: python, azure-functions, kql

I have an Azure Function with Python runtime. It works well with no big issues. I have an alert setup for times when failures occur. The alert went off and I can't figure out why.

**Scenario**:

- The function executed just fine 4/18/2023 ~07:23:13 (shown below)
- Then the next `trace` at 4/18/2023 ~08:33:49 shows the host shutting down...

**What is the process for troubleshooting a shutdown like this?**

**KQL query**:

```
traces
| where timestamp between (todatetime('2023-04-18T06:00:00') .. todatetime('2023-04-18T08:40:00'))
| order by timestamp asc
```

[image]

**EDIT 1**:

[image]

Comment: Is there an error log where you can see what this "unhandled exception" was?

Comment: The `exceptions` log has a single entry (added to the post). Error is `
The operation 'GetMessageAsync' with id 'x' did not complete in '00:03:00'.` What did the function "timeout" on? How do I determine the cause?

Comment: You need to increase your function timeout, you can set it to 10 min or 5min as your process is gettting more time to execute. There may be many reasons(Dependencies, Loopings in your code).

Comment: The question I have is, how do I know why this happened? As you can see in the Trace logs, there was no triggers for an hour+ before this failure. There isn't a 5-10min timeout issue.

Comment: The error doesn't seem like a Kusto exception but its coming from a C# code (maybe the operation of the function itself).
I think you better open a ticket in which the accepting team could investigate the operation and activity IDs you hide here with the full exceptions details you can provide.